# Issue with getting MediaSource to work on Firefox 37.0.1 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: javascript, media-source

I'm running firefox version 37.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and do have the about:config's media.mediasource.enabled set to true.

But I can't get the simple MediaSource (from the Media Source Extensions) to work.  For example,
if I do this as my index.html:

```
<script>
console.log('test 1');
var        recvMediaSource = new MediaSource();
console.log('test 2');
</script>
```

I only see logged into the console 'test 1' but not 'test 2'.  So it appears that perhaps it's getting "stuck" in MediaSource in the above codee.  ANd yes, if comment out that "new MediaSource" line, then 'test 2' prints.  Any idea why this might be the case?   My goal is to get MediaSource feature working on this Firefox/Ubuntu combo.

Thanks.

Henry

Comment: Seems like from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource  MediaSource api should be supported....  But when I do the    statement "window.MediaSource = window.MediaSource || window.WebKitMediaSource;", I see that window.MediaSource is undefined in Firefox and defined in Chrome.  So, firefox 37 doesn't support Media Source API contrary to their website?

Comment: Its not working on firefox 37. But try to test the same on their firefox developer build (38 or onwards), and it works like charm.

Comment: It is not working for me firefox 38.0.1. Firefox does not support this and they should update their docs!